# What is the difference adt -target ipa-test and ipa-ad-hoc?

Tags: air

Using Adobe AIR packaging options to package for iOS, I came across these targets for ADT packager.

What is the difference between target `ipa-test` and `ipa-ad-hoc`?

According to Adobe AIR * ADT command documentation:

> **-target** The type of package to create. The supported package types are:
>
> - iOS package targets:
>
>   - `ipa-ad-hoc` — an iOS package for ad hoc distribution.
>   - `ipa-app-store` — an iOS package for Apple App store distribution.
>   - `ipa-debug` — an iOS package with extra debugging information. (The SWF files in the application must also be compiled with debugging
>       support.)
>   - `ipa-test` — an iOS package compiled without optimization or debugging information.
>   - `ipa-debug-interpreter` — functionally equivalent to a debug package, but compiles more quickly. However, the ActionScript bytecode
>       is interpreted and not translated to machine code. As a result, code
>       execution is slower in an interpreter package.
>   - `ipa-test-interpreter` — functionally equivalent to a test package, but compiles more quickly. However, the ActionScript bytecode is
>       interpreted and not translated to machine code. As a result, code
>       execution is slower in an interpreter package.

Source: [iOS package targets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-8000.html)

Does `ad-hoc` mean better performance?

*I suspect ad-hoc to be the closest thing to release/distribution IPA. Maybe even the same, just with different distr. policy?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ad-hoc means better performance. And also a way of distribution.

Also keep in mind to compile swf in release mode if it goes for release-distribution or if you're gonna test actual performance.